# If a body is floating in a static fluid, then the volume of the displaced fluid equal to the volume of the inmerse part of the object (proof)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

*Suppose an arbitrary body is floating in a static fluid, either totally or partially immersed in it, then the volume of the displaced fluid equal to the volume of the immersed fraction of the object.*

How can I prove it?. I've tried to do it, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Ever [take a bath](http://www.itsnotmagicitsscience.com/science.asp?newsid=381)?

Comment: Ok, but, the Archimedes principle states that the bouyant force is equal to the weight of the fluid displaced, then, I don't know how to mathematically prove that the volume of the immersed fraction of the object is equal to the volume of the displaced fluid. If it is a silly question, it's because I'm a noob

Comment: You can't mathematically prove this without first making certain assumptions, and making rigorous mathematical definitions of the physical concepts. Math doesn't know what a "static fluid" is, for example.  Another example of where assumptions matter is the fact that [not all volumes are additive](http://depts.washington.edu/chem/facilserv/lecturedemo/NonAdditiveVolumes.html).

Comment: So, Is it out of my reach?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of conservation of volume.
You need to start by stating assumptions that are obvious, prima-facia, that anyone would agree with, such as the liquid being incompressible.
Then you say, if one accepts these assumptions, then do like @User58220 said, assume the contrary and derive a contradiction.

Suppose you have to explain it to someone, and meet every objection they might have.
Then you have the outline of your proof.
It doesn't have to be "mathematical".

Answer (score 1):

Assume the contrary, the volume of liquid displaced is greater than, or less than, the volume of the object.

Then there is either a volume containing neither water nor object, or there is a volume occupied by both water and object.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to imagine that (for me) and if what you say is right, how could you prove it?

Comment: I agree that this is a good direction to take in this problem, but you might want to consider adding more to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can be done by the readings collected by doing simple archimedes displacement experiment. The volume of liquid overflow into the eureka can be considered as volume of object submerged since the water is initially full.

Comment: But, I would love to prove it mathematically, I've tried something, but nothing seems to work